# In grouped dataframe, summarize rows which contain certain value (e.g. zeros only) in set of columns with common substring in header [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Given the following dataframe:

```
dframe <- structure(list(id = c("294361-7349174-75411122", "294365-7645230-95464222", 
"291915-7345264-75464222", "291365-7345074-75164202", "594165-7345274-78444212", 
"234385-7335274-75464229", "734515-1345274-95464892", "201365-8345274-78464232", 
"294365-7315971-75464120", "591365-7345374-75464222", "394365-7345204-75411022", 
"494305-7345273-75464222", "291161-7345271-75461210", "294035-7345201-75464292", 
"298365-7345279-78864223", "294365-7345274-15964293", "294395-7345274-69464299", 
"899965-1345294-95464222", "194365-7145274-75464222", "194361-7349231-75464222", 
"294365-7345274-75464122", "191315-1345274-13464322", "794365-7349274-75464292", 
"214365-8318274-75464222", "394363-8341274-39494929"), gene = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ABC_1", "C_1", "XYZ_123"
), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("KO", "WT"), class = "factor"), class_A = c(0, 
1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 3), class_B = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to produce a new dataframe for data grouped per "group" and "gene". I want to output sum of rows per group in which both class_A and class_B columns contain the same, desired value - now I am interested in zeros.

Based on the answers provided in this thread: [Efficient way to create a dataframe with multiple summary columns based on a grouped dataframe using dplyr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792487/efficient-way-to-create-a-dataframe-with-multiple-summary-columns-based-on-a-gro)

I can achieve this with following code:

```
desired_dframe <- dframe %>% 
  group_by(group, gene) %>%
  summarise(counts_zero = sum(ifelse((class_A == 0 & class_B == 0), 1, 0)))
```

However, the above approach has one pitfall: the column names are hardcoded. In real life, I have dataframes with various number of columns denoting classes (and other names, e.g. "class_C", "class_Z" etc.). The common part of their names, is "class_". Based on this, I would like to consider all of the columns of interest.

I was playing around with `rowSums(dplyr::across(dplyr::starts_with('class_')==0))` to achieve this, yet with no avail. The function throws the error and I have no idea how to debug it.

Also, I was trying to incorporate this column into the @akrun's answer provided here:
[Efficient way to create a dataframe with multiple summary columns based on a grouped dataframe using dplyr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792487/efficient-way-to-create-a-dataframe-with-multiple-summary-columns-based-on-a-gro)

On the @akrun's request, I am putting this into the new thread.

Comment: @GregorThomas I deleted this thread, because I felt attacked (you made an assumption without even asking) and since our definitions of "enough" are incompatible, I realized that looking for help here is pointless. I was already fighting those facets for far too long. Instead of it, I plotted my data using different method, which fits them even better, is more visually pleasing and does not require producing dummy variables/reshaping the data etc.. Thank you for clarification though.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you very much for exhaustive answer. I will apply your suggestions if I'd be asking next time. I wanted to edit the question to be more specific, but since it was already flagged as duplicate, I thought it is now pointless, because no one would have a look at it anyway. Giving up with reordering the barplot & looking for another form turned out to be better option, as I found this: https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/upset-plot.html. Since it is totally different type of plot, I'd refrain from getting back to this thread.

Comment: Especially that for it to be really informative, I'd have to use another example - a real life dataframe, which is much larger than the slice I've shown for the sake of the barplot example. On this dummy the part below which shows relationships between the samples looks quite dull, the differences between the samples are not strikingly visible, this is not the most fortunate example for the upset plot. Anyways, have a nice day!

Comment: That upset plot is very cool, haven't seen that before!

Comment: I'm going to delete my earlier comments on this thread, as I they're not really pertinent here. You too have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is to get the `sum` of  `class_` columns, use `across` or `if_all` (more correct) i.e. loop over the `class_` columns in `if_all`, apply the condition `.x ==0`, which returns TRUE only if all the columns looped for that rows will be 0 or else it return FALSE.  Do the `sum` directly on the logical vector (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
library(dplyr)
dframe %>% 
  group_by(group, gene) %>% 
  summarise(counts_zero = sum(if_all(starts_with('class_'),
     ~ .x == 0)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  group gene    counts_zero
  <fct> <fct>         <int>
1 KO    ABC_1             2
2 KO    XYZ_123           4
3 WT    ABC_1             2
4 WT    C_1               0
5 WT    XYZ_123           1
```